# Tradeoffs around SKSwapChainPanel's DrawInBackground property?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, skiasharp

I am embedding a `SKSwapChainPanel` in a UWP/XAML `UserControl`. I noticed that it has a `DrawInBackground` property. I couldn't find documentation for it (only [3 google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=skswapchainpanel+DrawInBackground)) and assumed that it is there to increase performance by offloading rendering from the UI thread.

However, if I want to access properties of the `UserControl` (in which I am embedding the `SKSwapChainPanel`) inside the `PaintSurface` method, I need to do that from the UI thread to avoid the exception `The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread`.

If I dispatch that on the UI thread again (using `Dispatcher.RunAsync(...)`), it makes the `DrawInBackground` property redundant: although technically it will allow the rest of the calls in the draw method to be run in the background, I believe the draw calls depending on UI properties will need to wait for the UI thread to run and the UI code part to complete. This might create a bottleneck if one thread needs to wait / synchronise with the other thread.

How can I best work with the XAML UI properties, and what are the best practices around the `DrawInBackground` property?

Edit:
The "XAML UI properties" I referred to, are the `FontSize` property of the `UserControl` in which I am embedding my SkiaSharp canvas, and I was considering getting the `Height` / `Width` of the `SKSwapChainPanel` to calculate the scaling factor. Bottom line I only need to read them, and they can be cached indeed. I'm not sure if all of them offer change events, but I could indeed use a ViewModel to cache it.

Comment: By testing, after the Dispatcher.RunAsync() method completes, the execution of the code will still return to the background thread, so it will not make the DrawInBackground property redundant.

Comment: yes, technically it will allow the rest of the calls in the draw method to be run in the background. However, my suspicion was that then those draw calls will need to wait for the UI thread to run and the UI code part to complete before the draw calls can be made. This might create a bottleneck, losing the performance benefits, if one thread needs to wait / synchronise with the other thread. That is why I called it redundant.

Comment: If you want to access to the UI properties in a background thread, you need to return to the UI thread first, and when you update your UI from a background thread by calling RunAsync, it schedules the work on the UI thread and returns control to the caller immediately. It means after you dispatch the work on the UI thread, then the background thread will continue to work, it does not wait until the UI task is completed before it starts working.

Comment: I agree, but if I want to read the UI properties and use those values in the background thread, I do need to wait for the `Dispatcher.RunAsync(...)` to complete. That is why it will form a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards for tradeoffs, the OP is basically correct - it is a separate thread to the UI and interaction will throw. I believe that is the only real "downside".

I originally wanted to use a purely off-UI rendering system, but the issue was that sometimes you want to access the UI.

If you have a very high rate of updates, then switching to a non-UI thread is also great as it allows the other controls to run without interruption. One thing to know is that mouse and keyboard interaction may interrupt or be interrupted with a high refresh rate. In these cases, it is better to draw on a background thread.

And, when you have to access the UI components, there are 2 ways to do this - both involving a "caching" type of style. You obviously know about requesting an dispatcher run on the UI thread to read data, but this blocks the rendering.

The alternatives are really either block and cache the result. When something changes, then you invalidate the cache and the next loop will read it. Often, he data changes less than 60 fps, so you get a small benefit. The other way is to actually allow the updates from the view to go to local fields or properties that are not tied to the UI. This means that the UI updates some cache/state, and the rendering does just one thing - render as fast as possible.

If you are using view models, then the "cache" could be the VM itself, or if you need some view property - for example the size - then you can subscribe to size change events and update a local field.

I suppose the real answer lies in *what* you are wanting from the UI controls and if/how they can be cached or accessed from some background thread. Let me know and I can edit this answer.

**EDIT**

You might be able to use data binding to a private/internal property from a property that you wish to track to a plain, non-observable property. They you don't have to manually track changes.

For scaling, most views have a "scale factor" type of property: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/skiasharp.views.uwp.angleswapchainpanel.contentsscale

Comment: I added an edit with an explanation about the properties